# how to escape special characters within eval using javascript?

Tags: javascript, eval, escaping

```
var input;

// method 1
input = document.getElementById('address').value;
alert(input)

// method 2
eval('input = "'+document.getElementById('address').value+'"')
alert(input)
```

**method 1 is working** fine, but **method 2 is not working** when **newline** characters are inputted and it says **"unterminated string literal"**.

I need to store values using **eval** anyway. So please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\\n")` to escape the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are actually evaluating code that looks like this, which is ofcourse wrong in javascript

```
​var test = "Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet"; ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Why do you need the eval? It looks not really necessary in this case. Maybe we can help you get around the eval?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   const address = document.getElementById('address').value
   eval('input = ' + JSON.stringify(String(address)))
```

String(address) will guarantee that the object is a string.
JSON.stringify will return a double quoted string parsable with eval.